# SQL select distinct on one field MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are several question like this one but I feel I've spent more than enough time trying different examples for a simple little hobby project. Yes, I'm being lazy, but in my defense, It's Saturday morning...

So I've got a table, Items which have the following fields (and more irrelevant ones):
id (varchar), product (varchar), provider (varchar)

Items are part of products, and have a provider.

I want to write a query where I can get one item per product a given provider supplies.

So even if a provider supplies all items for a product, I just want one of those.

I know I can't do distinct on only one field but I've tried with different variants o joins.
Should be simple for those of you who actually know what you're doing.

Comment: At least show a little effort an show what you've done so far - this is not a "give me teh codez"-page.

Comment: I agree with you, I was prepared for atleast one -1

Comment: I did: Items which have the following fields (and more irrelevant ones): id (varchar), product (varchar), provider (varchar) . The irrelevant ones are just information about that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql have gone to the trouble of creating a website that contains a manual and all references to its features.

for distinct:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

```
select DISTINCT(columnname) from MYTABLE where RULESAPPLY
```

Comment: I don't want just the product field. I want all fields, but I want the product field to be the one that's distinct. As far as I know, and from what I've seen you cannot do this with distinct.

Comment: then use group by column name

Comment: also select DISTINCT(column), column2, column3, column4 from TABLE   should work too   not too sure what your source of tutorials actually is !

Comment: damnit, I'm not completely awake yet... I even knew I could do that, but for some reason I thought I'd have to do a complex query. Thx, it works with just adding a group by.

Comment: Well I tried "select distinct(product), id, provider where provider = 'provider1'" but I got an error from phpmyadmin about my syntax being wrong. And I know I've read somewhere that it wouldn't work.

Comment: @JayLev if you only want distinct from the product field, what value to pick from the rest of the columns that belong to a group of product field that are the same? The max, min, first?

Comment: hmmm strange SELECT DISTINCT (
deliveryName
), deliveryFilename
FROM  `Deliveries` 
WHERE 1 
LIMIT 0 , 100   in phpmyadmin returns 6 results ??????   never mind anyway normal method would be to group anyway

Comment: @magnus, the first where I have a given provider.

Comment: @minus4, I just tried again and didn't get the error this time, must've done something else wrong the first time. But I still got duplicate products that way. Never mind, works with group by.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Distinct` operator

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...
```

Comment: I've tried that: select distinct * from items where provider = 'provider1'. But it still gives me several items from the same produkt.